# Compile Failed Storyboard

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, storyboard, exit-code, ibtool

### Output in Log:

**ibtoold(1642,0x7fff78b64960) malloc: error for object 0x7fbf38056a08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255**

---

### The setup:

The project was received through git. I had tried to compiled the project, but got the eror. Nothing was changed before, but used the new version of Xcode 4.3 instead of 4.2.

---

Things I tried:

- Clean and Rebuild
- Create new project and import files and sources into new project
- Restart Computer & Xcode

---

### Conclusion

There were people that have similar problems, but not the exact problem. Please forgive me if I don't see the obvious problem, I can't figure out what is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reported bug already filed with Apple. I have tried duplicating the issue and the error occurred randomly when creating iPad storyboards only (for me). My iPhone storyboard has 30+ views with zero issues. Makes it pretty tough to complete a Universal app as of right now. It appears to be a memory issue since I can make the error occur by simply removing the last view I added (view contains a lot of UILabels also)

Answer (score 1):

YMMV but closing and opening the Xcode project resolved the issue for me. It occurred after I git stash popped some storyboard changes.